# Programar Online em C?

Tags: c

Pretendo saber se existe algum site que permita programar online, tentei utilizar o Cloud9 IDE, mas não consigo programar em C, alguém conhece algum site para programar em C, sem ter que instalar qualquer programa?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Deve haver uma lista de compiladores online na wiki das tags [<kbd>**C**</kbd>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) e [<kbd>**C++**</kbd>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/c++/info). Em geral os sites que aceitam C++ devem também aceitar C. Aqui alguns:

- [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/)
- [Ideone](http://ideone.com/)
- [Codepad](http://codepad.org/)
- [Rextester](http://rextester.com/runcode)

Comment: Não sei se sua intenção era usar o `kbd` mesmo, mas pra fazer tags é `[tag:c]` => [tag:c] , renderiza melhor no post do que no comment.

Comment: @brasofilo O problema de fazer tags assim é que elas linkam para a lista de perguntas, não para a página de informações (que é meio difícil de descobrir que existe, para os novatos).

Comment: Ah, é verdade... Pois sim, eu mesmo custei a descobrir as wiki de tags...

Answer (score 5):

Para programas básicos tens o [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/). Muito parecido com esse, tens o [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/) que tem a funcionalidade de aceitar input.

Answer (score 4):

Experimenta o http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php ou o https://compilr.com/c-compiler. O primeiro dá pra usar direto, o segundo é mais completo mas exige que você crie uma conta (acho que da pra associar com a do facebook mesmo) :)

Answer (score 2):

Ja utilizei esse site e é muito útil. 
https://compilr.com/